# How do I change a function's parameters in R?

Tags: r

I am using multinom() function from nnet R package to perform a mutlinomial logistic regression on unordered multi categorical data and the function stops after 100 iterations. Since I need to perform more than 100 iterations, I want to change the "maxit" parameter of nnet package from 100 to 1000. This parameter is inside nnet's documentation:

```
nnet(formula, data, weights, ...,
     subset, na.action, contrasts = NULL)

## Default S3 method:
nnet(x, y, weights, size, Wts, mask,
     linout = FALSE, entropy = FALSE, softmax = FALSE,
     censored = FALSE, skip = FALSE, rang = 0.7, decay = 0,
     maxit = 100, Hess = FALSE, trace = TRUE, MaxNWts = 1000,
     abstol = 1.0e-4, reltol = 1.0e-8, ...)
```

Does anyone know how can I change maxit?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use the `...` argument of `multinom`. `?multinom` says "`...` additional arguments for `nnet`. Generally, `...` can be used by function to pass arguments along to other functions that they call internally. So

```
multinom(low ~ ., bwt, maxit = 1000)
```

(modifying the example from `?multinom`)

Comment: ;) 

(I am so new here)